# Convert map to get size of lists in each element

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a Map of element where each element has a List as its value

e.g.

`Map(a -> List(a, a), b -> List(b, b), l -> List(l, l, l), h -> List(h)`)

I want to convert this so that each value is the size of List e.g.

`Map(a -> 2, b -> 2, l -> 3, h -> 1`)

I try:

```
myMap.map(x => x.size())
```

which gives...

```
error: value size is not a member of (Char, List[Char])
```

Any tips how I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution: `myMap.mapValues(x => x.size)`. Standard `map` maps over key-value pairs.

Comment: I had to do myMap.mapValues(x => x.size)  size() gives Int does not take parameters  Not sure why.

Comment: @MoreThanFive Right, I corrected my answer. `size` is a method with no parameter lists so you can't call it giving any parameter lists (even an empty one). That's because scala differentiates between methods declared like `def size: Int` and `def size(): Int`.